# How can I assert value created in void method?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I have class

```
public class CloneUserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public CloneUserService(UserRepository userRepository, PersonRepository personRepository, OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }


    public void createFromTemplate(String templateUserId) {
        User templateUser = userRepository.getUserById(templateUserId);
        Person templatePerson = personRepository.getPersonByUserId(templateUserId);
        List<Order> templateOrders = orderRepository.getOrdersByUserId(templateUserId);

        User newUser = cloneUserFromTemplate(templateUser);
        newUser.setId("newId");
        userRepository.save(newUser);

        Person newPerson = clonePersonFromTemplate(templatePerson);
        newPerson.setUser(newUser);
        newPerson.setId("newId");
        personRepository.save(newPerson);

        for (Order templateOrder : templateOrders) {
            Order newOrder =  cloneOrderFromTemplate(templateOrder);
            newOrder.setId("newId");
            newOrder.setUSer(newUser);
            orderRepository.save(newOrder);
        }

    }

    private Order cloneOrderFromTemplate(Order templateOrder) {
        //logic
        return null;
    }

    private Person clonePersonFromTemplate(Person templatePerson) {
        //logic
        return null;
    }

    private User cloneUserFromTemplate(User templateUser) {
        //logic
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to test this method `createFromTemplate`.

I create this test. I create stabs for each repository and store saved object into this stub. And I add the additional method for getting this object for the assertion. 
It works. But I have 2 problems:

1. My template object is mutable. It is not a big problem but it is a fact.
2. If I add new methods to repository interface I must implement it in stubs.

Mu question - How can I test cloned objects like theses from my example?

I don't use spring and H2DB or another in-memory database. 
 I have a MongoDB database.
 If I use mockito I will not understand how to assert new objects in void method.

```
class CloneUserServiceTest {

    private CloneUserService cloneUserService;
    private UserRepositoryStub userRepository;
    private PersonRepositoryStub personRepository;
    private OrderRepositoryStub orderRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        User templateUser = new User();
        Person templatePerson = new Person();
        List<Order> templateOrders = Collections.singletonList(new Order());

        userRepository = new UserRepositoryStub(templateUser);
        personRepository = new PersonRepositoryStub(templatePerson);
        orderRepository = new OrderRepositoryStub(templateOrders);

        cloneUserService = new CloneUserService(userRepository, personRepository, orderRepository);
    }

    @Test
    void createFromTemplate() {
        cloneUserService.createFromTemplate("templateUserId");

        User newUser = userRepository.getNewUser();
//        assert newUser
        Person newPerson = personRepository.getNewPerson();
//        assert newPerson
        Order newOrder = orderRepository.getNewOrder();
//        assert newOrder
    }

    private static class UserRepositoryStub implements UserRepository {
        private User templateUser;
        private User newUser;

        public UserRepositoryStub(User templateUser) {
            this.templateUser = templateUser;
        }

        public User getUserById(String templateUserId) {
            return templateUser;
        }

        public void save(User newUser) {
            this.newUser = newUser;
        }

        public User getNewUser() {
            return newUser;
        }
    }

    private static class PersonRepositoryStub implements PersonRepository {
        private Person templatePerson;
        private Person newPerson;

        public PersonRepositoryStub(Person templatePerson) {
            this.templatePerson = templatePerson;
        }

        public Person getPersonByUserId(String templateUserId) {
            return templatePerson;
        }

        public void save(Person newPerson) {
            this.newPerson = newPerson;
        }

        public Person getNewPerson() {
            return newPerson;
        }
    }

    private static class OrderRepositoryStub implements OrderRepository {
        private List<Order> templateOrders;
        private Order newOrder;

        public OrderRepositoryStub(List<Order> templateOrders) {
            this.templateOrders = templateOrders;
        }

        public List<Order> getOrdersByUserId(String templateUserId) {
            return templateOrders;
        }

        public void save(Order newOrder) {
            this.newOrder = newOrder;
        }

        public Order getNewOrder() {
            return newOrder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into mocking frameworks like Mockito.  You don't have to write your own stubs if you go that route.  You just get a lightweight mock object from Mockito, and verify that the correct methods were called on it.  If you need to check that the arguments passed into the mocked method are correct, Mockito has a thing called ArgumentCaptors that let you extract the arguments and run validation against them.

Comment: @ Jordan I have some entity like User in DB. My void method selects this user, changes it and some fields and saves it as a new user. I need to compare the original user(template user) and new user created from the template user.

Comment: refer to https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html

Comment: _"I need to compare the original user(template user) and new user created from the template user."_ -- For a good unit test, you should be mocking everything that's not the unit under test.  So there would be no actual database connection.  Instead, you mock your repositories, and specify the exact return values you want.  You then use ArgumentCaptors to verify that the data passed to the  save methods matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario I would consider using mocking framework like Mockito.

Some main advantages:

1. **Adding new methods to repository interface doesn't require implementing it in stubs**
2. Supports exact-number-of-times and at-least-once verification
3. Allows flexible verification in order (e.g: verify in order what you want, not every single interaction)
4. Very nice and simple annotation syntax - @Mock, @InjectMocks, @Spy

Here is an example - maybe it will interest you:

```
// arrange
Warehouse mock = Mockito.mock(Warehouse.class);

//act
Order order = new Order(TALISKER, 50);
order.fill(warehouse); // fill will call remove() implicitly

// assert
Mockito.verify(warehouse).remove(TALISKER, 50); // verify that remove() method was actually called
```